# how to capture data from Velodyne32, network setting?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 64b with ROS Groovy and I'm trying to use velodyne 32.

I've followed the tutorial [Getting Started with the Velodyne HDL-32E] and rviz is not showing the scenes.

1. sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.100 <-- IP for my PC
2. sudo route add 192.168.18.108 eth0 <-- velodyne IP
3. roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 32e_points.launch calibration:=/home/vic/32db.yaml
4. rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne   >   configure as the tutorial said.

Rviz shows a message: "no tf data. Actual error: Fixed frame [/velodyne] does not exist ".

tcpdump and wireshark has captured no package, so my network is not properly set.

What is wrong in my network configuration? Thanks in advance.

---

Updated:
I fixed a wire inside Velodyne and now everything is fine . But I want to understand the network setting.

If I connect velodyne to my PC, with wireshark I detect ethernet packages from velodyne (.18.108) to broadcast (.3.255).

So, I do step 1 ( sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.100)  and my PC should "listen" these packages because it is now the receiver.

If I don't do step2, when I do step3  the  /velodyne_points is an active topic (rostopic list) but with no data (rostopic echo /velodyne_points).

So, Why do I need step 2? (sudo route add 192.168.18.108 eth0 ).
What does? I think is to say "admit packages from this IP". But, is it not the default option? to admit these?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117676/how-to-capture-data-from-velodyne32,-network-setting?/) by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the topic /velodyne_points is not published.

You can check at first that you received data from the velodyne with this command in a terminal :

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port 2368
```

If no packet are received then your network connection is not set properly.
In the velodyne documentation, it says that for "HDL-32E units, the destination IP address remains fixed at 192.168.3.255."
So I just set my PC address to 192.168.3.255 and the mask to 255.255.255.0.

If it works, in a second time you can check that raw packets are published in ROS :

```
rostopic hz /velodyne_packets
```

---

Originally posted by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) with karma: 365 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2014-02-16**:
Thanks. I used your commands to check that no topic was published. A wire inside Velodyne was disconnected, I fixed and it's allright.